# Android: Unusual NullPointerException When Working With Array of CheckBox

Tags: java, android, arrays, checkbox

The following code, which appears in an OnClickListener within a DialogFragment, throws a nullpointer exception when a certain button is pressed. I have a similar code setup within an Activity in another app and it's working flawlessly for months. I am being led to believe that this might be related to the fact that the code is inside a DialogFragment..?. Anyway, time to take a peek:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox[] ch= new CheckBox[3];
            int ids[]= new int[3];
            ch[0] = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
            ch[1] = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
            ch[2] = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
            for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
                if(ch[i].isChecked()){    //this is the line 35 mentioned in the LogCat
                    ids[i]=1;
                }
            }
            ((blahblahblah)getActivity()).updater(ids);
            dismiss();
        }
```

My LogCat follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.blah.blah.addrule$1.onClick(addrule.java:35)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

Comment: show your code for `addrule`

Comment: cross check your findViewByid references is they referring the correct check boxes id?

Comment: @suitianshi no offense but unless you let me in on your suspicions, I wont be able to do that. I am not allowed to.

Comment: @AndroidStudentM The references are just fine.

Comment: Try this. create three local checkBoxes variables out side onclick find your check boxes id's in onCreate or OncreateView method and assign that checkBoxes reference in onclick method instead of calling findViewById in onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `findViewById()` on the view `v` that was clicked. It doesn't have the checkboxes as children and nulls will be returned, and calling a method on null causes the NPE.

Call `findViewById()` on a view hierarchy that actually contains the checkboxes. In a fragment it's likely `getView()`.

Comment: Works like a charm. I would send you a free cat over the internet if I were able to. Thanks X1000000!

Answer (score 0):

You can get `findViewById()` using `getView()` but not `v`
Like:

```
ch[0] = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
ch[1] = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
ch[2] = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
```

Comment: v is the view that my onCreateView() is returned. I had used v previously to set an OnClickListener on a Button. I wasn't using v as though it were Android specific, LOL. I can't post all the code and it's pretty evident that this question was resolved by user:laalto an hour ago. Thanks for the down-vote though..

Comment: @FatFeralChubbyTabby But it was not clear so I added along with the code for better understanding.